# Adapter with ListView in my project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

i need help with Adapters in my project. In TelaCadastrados.java i used one adapter to show my listaDeItens<> components in a listView. But dont working.

Project in: https://github.com/brenosc2/seen.me

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use external links in your question. That's bad practice. Post all the relevant code in the question

Comment: Your list seems empty...

Comment: Look now, i made changes and now im using ListaDeItens attribute listaDeItensCulturais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have to fill your list.

In the activity you are doing this:

```
private ListaDeItens listaDeItens = new ListaDeItens();
...
ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, listaDeItens.getListaDeItens());
```

And in ListaDeItens :

```
public class ListaDeItens {
     List<ItemCultural> listaDeItensCulturais = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ItemCultural> getListaDeItens() {
        return listaDeItensCulturais;
    }
}
```

You are not filling the list, so there is nothing to show :)

You need to add some ItemCultural in it

Comment: now im using listaDeItensCulturais on adapter argument. But still dont showing.

Comment: @Override
    public void cadastrar(ItemCultural item) {
        getListaDeItens().add(item);
    }

on ItemCultural.java don't add? why? getListaDeItens() return listaDeItensCulturais.

Comment: But when are you using cadastrar(..)?